# Can't launch putty with remote command?

Tags: putty

I'm attempting to launch putty via the command line in such a way that it runs a command on the server (I want to create a windows shortcut, to tail a log file)

So far I have a batch file containing this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh -t -pw -m tail_catalina_out -load "myprofile"
```

And within my server I have a file at the root directory named tail_catalina_out with the following contents.

```
tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Putty launches and my session starts successfully, but no command appears to be carried out despite this? Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need `-ssh` with `-load profile` (and if you use a nonstandard port like my test it doesn't work at all); in fact you don't need it with `[user@]host` because it's the default
2. `-pw -m tail_catalina_out` uses `-m` as your password (which I hope is incorrect, so you should be reprompted unless publickey auth is set-up) and ignores `tail_catalina_out`
3. the file for `-m` must be **local** i.e. on the PuTTY machine not on the server (although the commands in it will be sent to, and must be valid on, the server)

Thus: `"\path\to\putty" -t -m localcmdfile -load profile`

You could also use `plink` which runs in the console and takes either `-m localfile` *or* the actual remote command on the command line after the last option (like the OpenSSH client `ssh`):

```
 "\path\to\plink" -t -load profile tail -f remotefile
```

As usual, you can omit the quotes around the path if it contains no space. Personally I use `\progra~2` instead of bothering with `"\program files (x86)"` but that's just me, and it may depend on a clean install (instead of upgrade).

Comment: Ah, how did I not notice the pw flag was still there! I think I got confused by the -M command as the documentation said "-m: read a remote command or script from a file" so I assumed the file was on the remote machine. I'll have to try this all when I'm next at work. Thanks a lot!